# What is the benefit of having to manually dismiss the keyboard in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm going through my app at the moment and fixing up all the textboxes for the keyboard to be dismissed when you tap away from them. I'm trying to figure out what the benefit is to having to dismiss them manually versus have them automatically disappear in the way that they appear when you tap on to a text input.

Can anyone give me an example of where this is beneficial?

Comment: I have no idea what goes on behind the scenes at weather.com, but if you use that site on an iPad (at least with Chrome), and tap the search field, a keyboard pops up. Unfortunately, whatever happens behind the scenes dismisses the keyboard before anything can be typed unless you wait a while. Perhaps it's not a good example, certainly not one involving code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it would be more appropriate to http://ux.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

There is little benefit in questioning Apple's wisdom, they do exactly as they see fit, you can either develop for their devices or not, they prolly couldn't care less...

That said the only real advantages that I perceive are.. 
1 you don't have to use the carriage return to finish text entry.  You may expect one or two carriage returns in the entry string because of some format you've implemented, treating 'return' like a 'tab' key... When you consider that the phone sized keyboard does not have room for a done button or whatever, I guess there wasn't a great deal of choice..

2 there may be times when text entry may not be complete, so you can refuse to dismiss the keyboard. For example you may be parsing the entry and not dismissing the keyboard because it is not a valid email address, or it doesn't fit requirement for a password etc.   I totally hear what you're saying though and I doubt there's many ios devs haven't questioned this too

Answer (score 0):

I will just give you few headlines that make sense for keyboard manually to be hidden,

- you are working on space constraint environment when you are on mobile app.
- there are other various aspects / elements on the screen that needed to be shown,as the keyboard takes up nearly '40%' of screen size.
- To let the system know that the input feed for the text field is over.
- The OS can not do telepathy to determine whether you are done with text input or you are  thinking about the phrases to type in. That's why keyboard is shown but needed to be hidden manually.
- human nature that they don't want to look at the things, which has done with the purpose.
- keyboard is just like a memory page that is being swapped-in when it is needed or else should be swapped out, the basics of an operating system.
- you can not afford to have a keyboard at all the times on screen in an app, when you have more important things to concentrate.

There can be 100s of ways to infer why you need to hide keyboard manually.

Hope I have clarified a few of them. If you are fixing issues with keyboard, it's better to write a category method that hides keyboard on some idle event.

Comment: I completely understand your points about the keyboard needing to be dismissed. My question is more why does it need to be manually dismissed rather than automatically dismissed when you tap away from the textfield / textinput.